# Divide two integers without using division, multiplication and mod operator, Flaw in bitmanipulation loop breaking equation

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058038/divide-two-integers-without-using-multiplication-division-and-mod-operator-in-j).

My query is, following approach-1 works, however the variation of it, that is approach-2 does not, rather it gives time limit exceeded. I can not find out why. I used [interviewbit](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/divide-integers/) portal to solve this question, and here it is in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/).

The issue is

```
for(; i<32 && ((B<<i)-A <=0); i++) {
}
```

works, but

```
for(; i<32 && (B<<i)<=A; i++) {
}
```

does not work, rather gives Time Limit Exceeds issue.

**Approach-1**

```
public class Solution {
    public int divide(int A, int B) {

        //Base Cases
        if (B == 1) {
            return A;
        }
        if (A == Integer.MIN_VALUE && B == -1) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        boolean neg = false;
        if((A<0 && B>0) || (A>0 && B<0)) neg=true;
        A = A==Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Math.abs(A);
        B = Math.abs(B);
        if(A<B) return 0;

        int res=0;
        while(A>=B) {
            int i=0;

            for(; i<32 && ((B<<i)-A <=0); i++) {
            }

            i--;
            res+=(1<<i);
            A-=(B<<i);
        }
      return neg? res*-1 : res;
    }
}
```

**Approach-2**

```
public class Solution {
    public int divide(int A, int B) {

        //Base Cases
        if (B == 1) {
            return A;
        }
        if (A == Integer.MIN_VALUE && B == -1) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        boolean neg = false;
        if((A<0 && B>0) || (A>0 && B<0)) neg=true;
        A = A==Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Math.abs(A);
        B=Math.abs(B);
        if(A<B) return 0;
        int res=0;

        while(A>=B) {
            int i=0;

            for(; i<32 && (B<<i)<=A; i++) {
            }

            i--;
            res+=(1<<i);
            A-=(B<<i);
        }
      return neg? res*-1 : res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the differences in parentheses.

Comment: (I'd use *terminating* a loop, and reserve *breaking* for using a `break` statement.)

Comment: Parenthesis difference does not seem to be the issue, `for(; i<32 && ((B<<i)<=A); i++) {
            }` it gives same TLE

Comment: Okay, I got the caveat, It seems for Integer.MAX_VALUE the loop is overflowing

Comment: Though I got the bug, can I someone explain in details why the loop is going infinite when `A` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` with approach-2, and how come approach-1 works